# Ventral View VS Dorsal View in cell experiments

Tags: cell-biology, microscopy, experiment

I am trying to understand the difference between ventral and dorsal view of "cell spreading on a substrate" experiment in this article https://rupress.org/jcb/article/205/1/83/37623/A-contractile-and-counterbalancing-adhesion-system. Consider figure 1:
[image]

How could I understand the way the image was taken and analyzed? Is it by taking image C and looking from above to get A?

If we rotate image A 90 degrees to the left we get image C? but that seems to be quite different from what is presenting lamella.

And what then are the broken yellow lines with respect to image C?

I think that the ventral view and dorsal view are just opposites. Why then we don't get the same resolutions in A and B? Because of the substrate?

Maybe very stupid questions, but I know nothing about experiments!